# Linux Disk Space Utilization using df -h

Tags: disk-usage

When I do `df -h` command output is as below.

[image]

However I've only allocated 32GB to my VM via virtual box. Even if the shared folder is disregarded, the sum of sizes (2.9 + 2.9 + 2.9 + 2.9 + 28 + 1 + 1 + 0.5) is more that 40 GB. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: tmpfs are ram filesystems => Don't take them into account when calculating disk space.

Answer (score 0):

`devtmpfs` and `tmpfs` are RAM filesystems, they don't use disk space.

The `CentOS_share` volume is apparently a ~1 TB removable disk mounted in `/media`, and it doesn't count for the 32 GB of disk space allocated to the VM.

In your case what matters in the count of the 32 GB are `/` and `/boot`. There are other partitions, probably a 2 GB swap partition and a 1 GB `/home`, which we cannot see in the picture as it is cropped.